# Are 2:05 hours enough for a Schengen to non-Schengen transfer in Schiphol?

Tags: short-connections, ams, missed-flights, klm, aeroflot

If everything goes according to plan, we arrive in the beginning of the July at Schiphol at 16:10 with a KL1782 from Hamburg and depart at 18:15 with a SU2695 to Moscow Sheremetyevo. Thus we have 2 hours and 5 minutes. Is it enough time?

We travel from a Schengen country (Germany) to a non-Schengen country (Russia), thus, according to KLM's website, we should expect additional security checks and customs inspections. However how long do they usually take in Schiphol? Plus, is a flight between Germany and Russia (with connection to the Netherlands) considered intercontintental (50 min transfer) or inter-european (40 min transfer)?

Actually I do think 2:05 hours should be enough, since according to recent flight statistic of these flights (around this week), these two flights often arrive too early and often depart too late. Granted, July may be a busier month, thus those statistics may not apply then, or I may be just unlucky at that day. Do you know whether these flights follow the same pattern at early July as today (mid May)?

In addition I have another question. Since KML and Aeroflot are in an alliance, IIRC I'd usually get the next flight for free, if I come too late to my flight, if the reason was not my fault. However does this also apply in Moscow Sheremetyevo, if I come too late, because the flight I was a given in Schiphol didn't match with my other flight?

PS: I booked my flight with flighttix.de. Does this change somehow the fact that I get another flight for free if I come too late to the other?

Answer (score 5):

The official minimum connection time entered into the GDS for this is 50 minutes. This means the computer will not sell you a tighter connection. I am not 100% 50 minutes is actually doable. But two hours? Plenty.

I am not sure where you are getting the inter-european 40 minutes from, MCT is given as Domestic-Domestic, Domestic-International, International-International, International-Domestic with exceptions given by groups of flight numbers (or sometimes a single flight -- the KLM flight coming from PVG has an unusually high MCT for example). I do not see an exception for KL1782.

Comment: Not sure 50 minutes is doable when connecting to Russia, last year I made my connection from Germany to UK in 40 minutes - less than MCT, because the incoming plane was 20 minutes late. This included a passport check but no additional security screening.

Comment: I got it from [here](https://www.klm.com/travel/de_en/prepare_for_travel/at_the_airport/connections/index.htm). **The standard transfer time at Amsterdam Airport Schiphol to a flight within Europe is 40 minutes and 50 minutes for an intercontinental flight.**

@Sabine I'm somewhat confused. Is security screening mandatory or is it only possible?

Comment: @Arhama before 2015 June, AMS had the security checks at the gate. It was horrible. They [centralized](http://www.futuretravelexperience.com/2015/04/behind-scenes-new-schiphol-security-experience/) it now.

Comment: @Arhama When I flew to Russia in 2008 from FRA, I had to pass two security screenings: the regular one between check-in desk and passport control and another one right next to the gate that connecting passengers had to pass, too. I have no idea if this second check is standard procedure for flights to Russia, hence my comment.